# Number of likes for a photo or album thru the API

Tags: facebook, api, photos, collect

Is it possible to get the number of likes for a photo or album using facebook's API?

This is a link to the open graph for an album

http://graph.facebook.com/99394368305

but it doesn't have the number of likes.

on facebook, you can see it has 2475+ likes

http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.99394368305.88399.40796308305

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the likes for a photo is easy, as you can see in the **[API Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)**:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=20531316728

For an album you can use the likes connection to get all members who liked that album. So, in your case:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/99394368305/likes
```

Notice that that won't return the count. You have to manually go through the results and count the likes. So you should definitely cache the results!

Comment: The first link points to a `page`'s data, not a photo, you might want to update your answer. You need to access `/likes` for a photo too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this as the URL to fetch what you need:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/albumID/photos?fields=id,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)&access_token=XXXXXX
```

Here is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085722/how-to-count-all-of-the-likes-and-comments-in-a-facebook-photo-album) that explains how in detail.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.